# How can I prevent light spill from an umbrella?

Tags: lighting, umbrella, lighting-modifiers

I've been reading [Strobist](http://www.strobist.blogspot.com/) lately and love the moody half-lit-half-dark effect in a lot of these types of photos. I'm a beginner and have a limited equipment budget, so I got a 45" reflective/shoot-through umbrella.

It gives great softness for the really low price. However, I find that I can't get the really dark areas/high contrast in my portraits. I think that this is because the excess light from my strobe is bouncing off my room walls and coming back at my subject. This effectively creates a new "ambient" light source (I've killed the real ambient) that prevents the deep shadows.

What are some good ways to work around this? Bonus points for being low-cost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is called "bookends"; 4x8 sheets of foam board, hinged together with tape.  Leave one side white and use it as a reflector, paint the other side black and use it to eat light.

Answer (score 5):

As light intensity falls off faster when you're close to the light source, you can minimize the effect of wall/ceiling reflections by putting the umbrella as close to your subject as possible.

Another very low cost option is to wait for the night and shoot outdoors.

Comment: Studio lighting, particularly softboxes, are almost always a whole lot closer than you'd think they'd be in practice. It took me nearly a year to learn that the right distance for an Elinchrom OctaLite from a subject was 3-4 feet most of the time -- you'd think that something that big should be wa-a-ay far back, but you'd be wrong.

Comment: @Stan: Well, the closer you put them, the softer the light is, so why buy *insanely huge* softbox when you can work with something that is only huge? :-)

Comment: "Insanely huge" is for half-figure or better without vertical fall-off (even a 1m^2 large softbox has falloff top & bottom for anything that goes below shoulder-height -- you have to do a sort of "quantum include" to avoid the Venus de Milo treatment).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try hanging some fabric remnants (I got 2 yards of black velvet for 5$ from hobby lobby) or some landscaping fabric from your walls.  Anything black and non-specular (I think thats right?) will do.  If your wife / roommate / mom won't permit such a thing, consider placing something closer to the light source, in a smaller format.  [Zack Arias](http://www.zackarias.com/) recommends bifold closet doors I think, but you could basically use an easily standable, movable piece of cardboard.  I think the strobist crowd calls these barn doors - you might search Hobby's site for that.

Answer (score 2):

I often use [black wrap](http://www.filmtools.com/blacfoilblac.html) to prevent spill. Great for general shaping of light.

Black wrap or black foil is a black aluminum foil that's primarily used to block out light and is attached to light fixtures and/or their barn doors.

Answer (score 1):

A great low cost option is to buy a [black sheet at Walmart](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Mainstays-Sheet-Set-Rich-Black/13437092) and use it as a "[black reflector](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1474/what-does-a-black-reflector-do)". Instead of adding light, it will subtract the light.

As well as being useful for photography, it never hurts to have a spare set of sheets for guests.